# DB2 SQL COUNT() result from first table

Tags: sql, db2

I posted something earlier and did not explain properly what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying a second time.

I want to return field value from two different table but want the count for only of the table. In this case the @SOP table. Right now it gives me total count of the @SOPREV table.

```
SELECT A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2 , COUNT(A.SOPSEQ) OVER() AS AAA
  FROM @SOP A
  INNER JOIN @SOPREV B on B.SOPSEQ = A.SOPSEQ
  WHERE UPPER(A.SOPSTS) = 'IN REVIEW' AND UPPER(B.REVSTS) = 'IN REVIEW'
  GROUP BY A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2
  ORDER BY A.SOPNBR, A.SOPREV

  OFFSET (:StartingRow - 1) * :NbrOfRows ROWS
  FETCH NEXT :NbrOfRows + 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Table @SOP:

```
|SOPSEQ   |SOPNBR |SOPSTS |     
|111      |123    |Review |          
|222      |456    |Review |          
|333      |789    |Review |
```

Table @SOPREV:

```
|SOPSEQ   |REVUSR2 |  
|111      |Mark    |         
|111      |John    |         
|333      |Erik    |
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: your answer is the expected result!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about what exactly you want, but if you want the count from the first table only, you can get it using `COUNT(DISTINCT column)` as shown below:

```
select
  a.sopseq,
  a.sopnbr,
  b.revusr2, 
  count(distinct a.sopseq) as aaa
from sop a
inner join soprev b on b.sopseq = a.sopseq
where upper(a.sopsts) = 'IN REVIEW' and upper(b.revsts) = 'IN REVIEW'
group by a.sopseq, a.sopnbr, b.revusr2
order by a.sopnbr, a.sopseq
```

Result:

```
SOPSEQ  SOPNBR  REVUSR2  AAA
------  ------  -------  ---
   111     123  Mark       1
   111     123  john       1
   333     789  Erik       1
```

For reference, the data script I used is:

```
create table sop (
  sopseq int,
  sopnbr int,
  sopsts varchar(10)
);

insert into sop (sopseq, sopnbr, sopsts) values 
  (111, 123, 'In Review'),
  (222, 456, 'In Review'),
  (333, 789, 'In Review');

create table soprev (
  sopseq int,
  revusr2 varchar(10),
  revsts varchar(10)
);

insert into soprev (sopseq, revusr2, revsts) values
  (111, 'Mark', 'In Review'),
  (111, 'john', 'In Review'),
  (333, 'Erik', 'In Review');
```

Comment: This worked. I did not know you could use distinct like that. I appreciate your help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

```
   SELECT A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2 , COUNT(A.SOPSEQ) OVER() AS AAA
   FROM @SOP A
   LEFT JOIN @SOPREV B on A.SOPSEQ = B.SOPSEQ 
   WHERE UPPER(A.SOPSTS) = 'IN REVIEW' AND UPPER(B.REVSTS) = 'IN REVIEW'
   GROUP BY A.SOPSEQ, A.SOPNBR, B.REVUSR2
   ORDER BY A.SOPNBR, A.SOPREV
```

This will return count from table @SOP.

Comment: same, it returns the count for @SOPREV

Comment: Can you post the expected result?

Comment: The Impaler answer worked for me. I appreciate your help! The expected result is the total of the @SOP table